# Finalize and garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Could you help me understand garbage collection.

When I force finalization, I am supposed to occur in finzlize method. I placed a breakpoint there.

Well, when I start debugging, my program finishes without stopping at that breakpoint.
Could you help me understand what I'm doing wrongly?

```
public class Book {
    protected void finalize(){
        int a = 0; // Breakpoint;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Book a = new Book();
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Comment: finalize() isn't guaranteed to run every time. Never rely on it. For further reading: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/246070/why-is-the-finalize-method-included-in-java/

Comment: Read the javadoc of System.gc(): it doesn't force GC. Even if it did, you still have a reference to the book, so it wouldn't be gc'ed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, the new `Book` instance will not get garbage-collected because it is still referenced by the local variable `a`.

Also, as other answers suggest, it is not guaranteed that all objects are fully GCed (and their `finalize` called) before the `System.gc` returns. In particular, the `finalize` method may be called later in a different thread. If your main application terminates before that, the method may not get called at all.

Comment: If that's the case, you should change your code in this fashion: `Book a = new Book();` -> `new Book();`

Comment: Just avoiding the local variable is not enough. You should also do some work after `System.gc` to provide JVM with enough time before the application terminates.

Answer (score 1):

**Garbage collection** is the process of looking at heap memory, identifying which objects are in use and which are not, and deleting the unused objects.

An in **use object**, or a referenced object, means that some part of your program still maintains a pointer to that object.

An **unused object**, or unreferenced object, is no longer referenced by any part of your program. So the memory used by an unreferenced object can be reclaimed.

For more details [Java Memory Management](http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx) and [How Garbage Collection works in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html)